# How to access code of my Azure website?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I dropped my hard drive which contained all my code and now it won't plug in to my computer. I need the code to my Azure website which I deployed earlier asap. Is there a way for me to access this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are multiple ways.

- Using the deployment credentials you can connect via FTP and download the files.
- Using [Git source control](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/) you can add your azure web app as a remote reference and clone it locally.

Comment: I tried via FTP, but am only able to see the front end files? Is there a way for me to get to my backend code?

Comment: More than likely no. Your code behind files are stored locally on your machine. When you deploy to Azure you are just deploying the files you need to run the site. Can you provide some more information? What language did you develop in?

Comment: C# backend. It was an ASP.NET MVC application

Comment: I don't see how the website could run without those?

Comment: When you build your application, your code gets compiled into .dll files that are in your /bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to be pretty but once you get your binaries via FTP you can use a Reflector library to decompile your binaries and generate source code from them.

It won't be as good as the original source code, but it'll be functionally equivalent and will make it easier for you get back to where you were.